# how to getAdapterPosition in RecyclerView ViewHolder with Android Annotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

I use android annotations and created [Recycler List](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Adapters-and-lists) , the problem is, if i delete something in holder and update adapter using through listner using `notifyItemRemoved(position);`. the position in the holder is not updating.

```
 @EBean
    public static class CheckListAdapter extends RecyclerViewAdapterBase<LinkedHashMap<String, String>, HolderItemView>
            implements AdapterListener {

        private final Context mContext;

        public CheckListAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected HolderItemView onCreateItemView(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return CheckListFragment_.HolderItemView_.build(mContext);
        }

        public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> list) {
            items.clear();
            items.addAll(list);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addData(LinkedHashMap<String, String> map) {
            items.add(map);
            notifyItemChanged(items.size() - 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewWrapper<HolderItemView> holder, int position) {
            HolderItemView view = holder.getView();
            view.bind(items, position, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void itemRemoved(int position) {
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
```

HolderItemView.java

```
 @EViewGroup(R.layout.item_checklist)
    public static class HolderItemView extends LinearLayout {
        private Context mContext;
        @ViewById
        AppCompatCheckBox checkbox;
        @ViewById
        TextView checklist_tv;
        @ViewById
        EditText checklist_et;
        @ViewById
        ImageView deleteButton;
        private AdapterListener mListener;
        private List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> mainMap;
        private int position;

        public HolderItemView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mContext = context;
        }

        public void bind(List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> mainMap, int position, AdapterListener mListener) {
            this.mainMap = mainMap;
            this.position = position;
            this.mListener = mListener;
            if (mainMap.get(position).get("title").isEmpty()) {
                checklist_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                checklist_et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                checklist_tv.setText("");
                checklist_et.setText("");
            } else {
                checklist_tv.setText(mainMap.get(position).get("title"));
            }
            checklist_et.setOnEditorActionListener(editListener);
            checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkChangeListener);

        }

        @Click
        public void checklist_tv() {
            checklist_et.setText(checklist_tv.getText());
            checklist_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checklist_et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Click
        public void deleteButton() {
            mainMap.remove(position);
            mListener.itemRemoved(position);
        }

        private TextView.OnEditorActionListener editListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    checklist_et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    checklist_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    checklist_tv.setText(checklist_et.getText());
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(checklist_et.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    checklist_tv.setPaintFlags(checklist_tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                } else {
                    checklist_tv.setPaintFlags(checklist_tv.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public interface AdapterListener {
        void itemRemoved(int position);
    }
```

RecyclerViewAdapterBase.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class RecyclerViewAdapterBase<T, V extends View> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewWrapper<V>> {

    protected List<T> items;

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public final ViewWrapper<V> onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewWrapper<>(onCreateItemView(parent, viewType));
    }

    protected abstract V onCreateItemView(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    // additional methods to manipulate the items
}
```

ViewWrapper.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

public class ViewWrapper<V extends View> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private V view;

    public ViewWrapper(V itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
    }

    public V getView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code, what you tried

Comment: I have updated the code, please have a look @Gaurav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you remove an item from recycler view you need to notify item range change. So you need to do something like this

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);.
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, arrayList.size());
```

Comment: Doesn't this look weird with the default RecyclerView animations?